# visual studio errors LNK1104 and The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designed

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2015

i know its a duplicated question but none of the solutions i found worked for me.

i created new CLR empty project and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(CodeDomDesignerLoaderNoRootSerializer);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2)&rd=true) error appeared so i searched for solution and none of them worked for me except that i close myform.h and opened it again from the solution explorer and was working fine then i installed opencv from the NuGet Package Manager and when i added the includes

```
#include "opencv2\core\core.hpp"
#include "opencv\cv.h"
#include "opencv\highgui.h"
#include "opencv2\opencv.hpp"
```

that error appeared

```
Error   LNK1104 cannot open file 'C:\Users\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\algorithms\projectimage\x64\Debug\projectimage.exe'
```

then i also searched for solution and none of them solved it so i tried closing the whole project and open it again, the two errors appeared together and i tried closing myform.h and opening it again but it doesnt go away so any help in solving the two errors please

[image]

My Main

```
#include "MyForm.h"
using namespace System;
#include "opencv2\core\core.hpp"
#include "opencv\cv.h"
#include "opencv\highgui.h"
#include "opencv2\opencv.hpp"
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

[STAThread]
void main() {
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    projectimage::MyForm form;
    Application::Run(%form);

}
```

NOTE: am using visual studio 2015 and opencv version 2.4.11 c++

Comment: Does opencv work in windows forms without a wrapper?

Comment: @drescherjm no it only works without windows form